# Upper bound of $n$th derivative of reciprocal of $\zeta$

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory

Is there any bound or asymptotic available for:

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s} \log^k{n}$$

when $\Re(s) > 1$ and $k \to \infty$ ?

References are welcome.

Comment: If $s$ is not too far from the origin so that $-2$ is the closest $0$ to $s$ of $\zeta(x)$, by Cauchy the order of magnitude should be around $k!/|s+2|^k$.

Comment: And on the other hand, if the real part of $s$ is large, then the entire series is very close to its first term $-(\log2)^k/2^s$.

Comment: @HenriCohen thank you. Not a sharper bound, right? I tried the one you suggested for my application and is still too big.

Comment: @GregMartin thank you. Unfortunately I am very interested in the particular case $\Re(s)=\frac{3}{2}$

Comment: A single term in the sum, when $\log n$ is near $k$, has size about $k^k/e^{3k/2}$, which is superexponential in $k$. (Having $\log n$ near $2k/3$ does even a little better I think.) That suggests that getting even an exponential upper bound is unlikely. One can probably find a value of $t$ such that $\Re(n^{it})$ is very close to $\mu(n)$ for all $n$ near $e^k$ or $e^{2k/3}$, so that those large terms don't even cancel.

Comment: @GregMartin exactly, that is why this problem is so complicated. At the end is no more than the  R.H. You can see these terms as the Taylor coefficients of $1/\zeta(s)$, centered at an arbitrary heigh $h$ and with real part $\frac{3}{2}$. Sharply bounding it, could yield to having a radius of convergence close to $1$ for any $h$ and that  would imply R.H. since would mean no poles  of inverse of $\zeta$ on the critical strip  $\frac{1}{2}<\Re(s) < 1$.

Comment: This problem itself doesn't seem complicated, but I agree that gaining nontrivial information about the zeros of $\zeta(s)$ from such bounds is very ambitious.

Comment: @GregMartin if we can prove that  $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^{\frac{3}{2} + it}} \log^k{n} = o(e^{-k} k^{k+1})$ would be great since I believe to have the  rest of the demonstration to conclude all zeros of $\zeta$ lie on the critical line and this is the unique missing piece. I presume it will be impossible though ;-)

Comment: @HenriCohen : can you please elaborate a bit more on the order of magnitude? What do you mean by "by Cauchy..."?